# High pass filter in Python

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

I'm recording live audio in 5 second clips with Python and want to cut out all sound below a certain frequency e.g. 10kHz. This is my script so far:

```
import pyaudio, wave, time, sys, os
from array import array
from scipy import signal

FORMAT=pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS=1
CHUNK=1024
RATE=44100 
RECORD_SECONDS=5

def butter_highpass(cutoff, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    b, a = signal.butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='high', analog=False)
    return b, a

def butter_highpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_highpass(cutoff, fs, order=order)
    y = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data)
    return y
    
audio=pyaudio.PyAudio() 

stream=audio.open(format=FORMAT,channels=CHANNELS, 
                  rate=RATE,
                  input=True,
                  frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
while True:
    # read data
    data=stream.read(CHUNK)
    data_chunk=array('h',data)
    data_chunk = butter_highpass_filter(data_chunk,10000,RATE)
    frames=[]
    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)
    # write to file
    words = ["RECORDING-", time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"), ".wav"]
    FILE_NAME= "".join(words) 
    wavfile=wave.open(FILE_NAME,'wb')
    wavfile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wavfile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wavfile.setframerate(RATE)
    wavfile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
    wavfile.close()
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I want to cut out all (or as much as possible of the) sound below the specified frequency. Why doesn't the filter I'm using seem to cut out the sound below 10kHz? How can I make it work?

Comment: This essentially 2 questions. How do you create a digital high pass Filter and how do you apply a filter in Python. If you’re doing this as a means to an end, github will have tons of examples for you to leech from https://gist.github.com/endolith/5455375 if you are actually interested in filter design, say as part of a University course, I‘d really strongly recommend engaging with the staff in your institution, also dsp.stackexchange.com has a ton of resources

Comment: Without a genuine attempt, that is to say code that does not have a space labelled ENTER SOLUTION HERE , you are unlikely to get a good response from the community.

Comment: Hi @fdcpp. Added some code I've tried (didn't include before as was trying to be succinct). I don't see why this is two questions - it's just one task I want to achieve, I don't think I could break it down any further.

Comment: I have to disagree, understanding filters is language agnostic, it is fundamentally the same process regardless of wether you use Python, C, Java &c… A Python implementation _may_ generate some language specific questions. If you are interested in filters, tackle that first. If you aren’t, I recommend trying to search for a few solutions (GitHub would be a good start). _I found some code, it doesn’t work, help_ is sort of against the spirit of SO.

Comment: Also, the Butterworth functions are in a separate script. It would be a good idea to demonstrate how you have tried to integrate those functions into what you currently have

Comment: You might want to consider the impossibility of an ideal `brick-wall` filter - which seems to be what you're after.   I suggest finding some courseware on digital signals and sampling theory (and associated mathematics, of which there is a great deal).  First and second year undergraduate material on an Elec. Eng degree.

Comment: SO is great for questions rooted in programming, but sadly this question does spread across domains and in its initial form it was tricky to ascertain what you were looking to gain with an answer. For good SO usage, my advice to my own students is _click on a tag and sort by votes_ from there you’ll get a good idea on what are considered valuable questions and valuable to those interested in that tag.

Comment: With regard to comment tone, apologies, I don’t aim to be disparaging, quite the opposite. I like to encourage programmers to breakdown there problems and attempt a solution as much as possible. The down vote in this case was two-fold. The initial form of the question wasn’t great and combined with the fact you are not a new SO user, I hoped this would encourage you to improve the question, especially if it was written in good faith. Once this is at a stage that shows an attempt to use the filter functions provided, I think the question would no longer be in a state of requiring a down vote.

Comment: @fdcpp I've rephrased the question to be as clear as possible. Why doesn't the filter I'm using seem to cut out the sound below 10kHz?

Comment: Lovely, I’m not in a position to run this right now, should be able to in a few hours. Shooting from the hip it looks like you are passing integers to the filter function which expects floats. You are also sending the data in chunks, the filter looks to expect the entire signal to filtered

Comment: Internally the filter is just using [scipy.signal.filtfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html#scipy.signal.filtfilt) which doesn’t have any way to remember state (basically not great for real-time applications). However, you’re not alone in that problem so check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/50108374/8876321

Comment: Apologies, answer below is probably more accurate https://stackoverflow.com/a/67815086/8876321

Comment: having had time to review this, you use `butter_highpass_filter` in your main `while` loop but not in the `for` loop. This means you apply the filter to `data_chunk` but you never actually use it

Answer (score 3):

### Brief

The goal is to apply a brick-wall 10 kHz high-pass filter to audio, then save it. Audio is recorded continuously and saved in 5 second snippets to separate `.wav` files.

### What we have so far

At the moment the current script:

- declares a function to apply a butterworth high-pass filter (`butter_high-pass_filter`) whose output is an array of floating point values

  - `butter_high-pass_filter` uses [signal.filtfilt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html#scipy.signal.filtfilt)
  - the input to the function is in short format  (bug 1)

```py
data_chunk=array('h',data)
data_chunk = butter_high-pass_filter(data_chunk,10000,RATE)
```

- `data_chunk` is never used, so a high passed frame of audio is never saved to file (bug 2)
- data is read for 5 seconds worth audio

```py
frames=[]
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(data)
```

- stream.read is blocking, so this will wait until the correct amount of audio has been read.
- collected data is then written to a `wav` file in the same format

```py
words = ["RECORDING-", time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"), ".wav"]
FILE_NAME= "".join(words)
wavfile=wave.open(FILE_NAME,'wb')
wavfile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wavfile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wavfile.setframerate(RATE)
wavfile.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wavfile.close()
```

### Solution

The problem here is that the solutions is multifaceted and requires multiple parts that are currently missing from the current script.
Also, to avoid further complications a slightly different approach needs to be taken than the one originally intended. Rather than applying a filter in real-time a filter can simply be applied to the `wav` sample data before it is saved.
This

- Removes the need for dealing with filter state continuity
- limits the need for casting back and forth between data types

Also, the outer forever `while` loop has been removed. Timing and memory start to become an issue. The program can simply be re-run over and over until there is more clarity on the use case covering

- Why must the audio be high pass filtered?
- Why can't the filtering take place after all data is recorded (i.e. applied to `wav` files?
- Why does data have to be saved?
- Are there limitations on data format? bit-depth? sampling rate?

Until those are answered there are too many possible routes each with limitation that can realistically be covered in a single answer.

#### Breakdown

Full breakdown for the process will be

1. Declare a function that takes floating point sample data as input and high pass filters with floating point data as ouput
2. concatenate 5 seconds of byte-string data from pyaudio into a single variable
3. unpack data as a 16-bit (signed short) format array of samples
4. scale samples to floating point format between 1.0 and -1.0
5. send data to high pass filter
6. scale filter samples in the range of 16-bit (signed short) format
7. pack 16-bit filtered samples into a byte string
8. write filtered byte-string data to a wav file.

#### Script

```py
import pyaudio, wave, time, sys, os, struct
from array import array
from scipy import signal

# 1. Declare a function that takes floating point sample data as input and high pass
#    filters with floating point data as output
# 2. concatenate 5 seconds of byte-string data from PyAudio into a single variable
# 3. unpack data as a 16-bit (signed short) format array of samples
# 4. scale samples to floating point format between 1.0 and -1.0
# 5. send data to high pass filter
# 6. scale filter samples in the range of 16-bit (signed short) format
# 7. pack 16-bit filtered samples into a byte string
# 8. write filtered byte-string data to a wav file.

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# 1. Declare High Pass Filter

def butter_highpass(cutoff: float, fs: float, order: int = 5) -> tuple:
    """
    Generate FIR and IIR coefficients for a butterworth highpass filter

    :param cutoff: cutoff frequency (hz)
    :param fs: sampling rate
    :param order: filter order
    :return: tuple of filter coefficients
    """
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    b, a = signal.butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='high', analog=False)
    return b, a


def butter_highpass_filter(data: [float], cutoff: float, fs: float, order: int = 5) -> [float]:
    """
    apply a butterworth high pass filter to sample data in floating point format

    :param data: float sample data array
    :param cutoff: filter cutoff (hz)
    :param fs: sample data sampling rate
    :param order: filter order
    :return: floating point array of filtered sample data
    """
    b, a = butter_highpass(cutoff, fs, order=order)
    y = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data)
    return y

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Init Global Variables

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
CHUNK = 1024
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Main Program

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # 2. concat 5 seconds of data into a single string
    frames = b''
    for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
        frames += stream.read(CHUNK)
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # 3. Unpack data as a  16 - bit
    sample_data = array('h', frames)
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # 4. scale samples to floating point format between 1.0 and -1.0
    samples = [sample_datum / (2**15) for sample_datum in sample_data]
    print("Max Amplitude:", max(samples))
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # 5. send data to high pass filter
    filtered_sample_data = butter_highpass_filter(samples, 10000.0, RATE)
    # filtered_sample_data = samples
    # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # 6. scale filter samples in the range of 16-bit (signed short) format
    #    (2 ** 14) for headroom (very lazy)
    sample_data_16_bit = [int(sample * (2 ** 14)) for sample in filtered_sample_data]
    # # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # # 7. pack 16-bit filtered samples into a byte string
    raw_data = [struct.pack('h', sample) for sample in sample_data_16_bit]
    # # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # # 8. Write Wav
    file_name = "".join(["RECORDING-", time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"), ".wav"])
    wavfile = wave.open(file_name, 'wb')
    wavfile.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
    wavfile.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
    wavfile.setframerate(RATE)
    wavfile.writeframes(b''.join(raw_data))
    wavfile.close()
```

#### Comments

Potential additions could include plotting the spectrum with `matplotlib`, normalising the filtered audio, encapsulating the process into custom functions, but these have been left as an exercise for the OP.

Below is included a screen shot of the audio spectrum after normalisation. As has been referenced in comments by @marco, the filter does have a slope, which is expected. This can be improved by increasing the order of the filter.

[image: Frequency Spectrum]

Comment: Thanks @fdcpp for a thorough answer. The reason it was set up with a while loop and to filter each data chunk was that I want to use the script to monitor live audio over the specified frequency. The reason `data_chunk` isn't used is because it then goes off to a different part of the script that I didn't include. Sorry, this wasn't obvious from my question. Thanks again for your help, I'll have a play with this and see if I can get it to fit with what I'm doing.

Comment: @Thomas If you want to monitor a frequency range, what restriction(s) does a Fourier Transform present that you are not using it?

Comment: This was suggested as an answer to another question https://stackoverflow.com/a/68388989/1640528 but the issue was that there is a lot of energy in the lower end of the spectrum, hence the need to filter it (although I'm open to suggestions for a better approach to this)

Comment: @Thomas In this instance, you could do a Fourier transform and simply ignore frequency bins < 10 kHz.